# Html table - Complex layout - specificel

Tags: html, html-table

I got this table  in a assignment but I'm have a hard time replicating it:

[image]
<sub>(source: [evc-cit.info](http://evc-cit.info/cit040/screenshots/complex_table.gif))</sub>

I can't seem to get the Xpath cell and the XSL transformation cell to share the 11 a.m to 2 p.m cells, can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a little hacky but you could say that 11:00 am - 2:00 pm is actually two rows, not one (each cell would then be a `rowspan=2`).  Then Xpath and XSL transformation cells would also be `rowspan=2` as there are 4 rows now. (Tuesday would be `rowspan=4`)

Answer (score 5):

I came here with same doubt, even though it has been answered but its not a great explanation, so it took me a long time to solve this.You need to put XLS transformations in third row, not in second row. Please see the code below.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta name="keywords" content="">
            <title>Table Practice</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="10px">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th rowspan="3">Day</th>
                        <th colspan="3">Seminar</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">Schedule</th>
                        <th rowspan="2">Topic</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Begin</th>
                        <th>End</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
        
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="2">Monday</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">8:00 a.m</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">5:00 p.m</td>
                        <td>Introduction to XML</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Validity: DTD and Relax NG</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="4">Tuesday</td>
                        <td>8:00 a.m</td>
                        <td>11:00 a.m</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">XPath</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="2">11:00 a.m</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">2:00 p.m</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="2">XSL transformation</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2:00 p.m</td>
                        <td>5:00 p.m</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Wednesday</td>
                        <td>8:00 a.m</td>
                        <td>12:00 p.m</td>
                        <td>XLS Formatting Objects</td>
                    </tr>
        
                </tbody>
            </table>
        
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1px">
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="3">Day</th>
            <th colspan="3">Seminar</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Schedule</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Topic</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Start</th>
            <th>End</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Monday</td>
            <td rowspan="2">8:00 a.m</td>
            <td rowspan="2">5:00 p.m</td>
            <td>Introduction to XML</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Validity: DTD and Relax NG</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4">Tuesday</td>
            <td>8:00 a.m</td>
            <td>5:00 p.m</td>
            <td rowspan="2" style="padding: 7px;">XPath</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">11:00 a.m</td>
            <td rowspan="2">2:00 p.m</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">XSL Transformations</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2:00 p.m</td>
            <td>5:00 p.m</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Wednesday</td>
            <td>8:00 a.m</td>
            <td>12:00 p.m</td>
            <td>XSL Formatting Objects</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
<!-- Hmmm -->
```

Comment: Next time please include some explanation, like: Great solutions/hack using  just `style="padding: 7px;"` on _XPath_.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table border="1" spacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="3">Day</th>
            <th colspan="3">Seminar</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Schedule</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Topic</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Begin</th>
            <th>End</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Monday</td>
            <td rowspan="2">8:00 a.m.</td>
            <td rowspan="2">5:00 p.m.</td>
            <td>Introduction to HTML</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Validity: DTD and Relax NG
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">Tuesday</td>
            <td>8:00 a.m.</td>
            <td>11:00 a.m.</td>
            <td rowspan="1.5">XPath</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11:00 a.m.</td>
            <td>2:00 p.m.</td>
            <td rowspan="1.5">XSL Transformations</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2:00 p.m.</td>
            <td>5:00 p.m.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Wednesday</td>
            <td>8:00 a.m.</td>
            <td>12:00 p.m.</td>
            <td>XSL Formatting Objects</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This answer could include some explanation

Answer (score 0):

> https://code.sololearn.com/WU73qCVhpik8
> this is my cord and this table is HTML and CSS combination
> this is possible but sum css add to run cord

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31673127)

Answer (score -1):

I came here with same doubt, even though it has been answered but it's not a great explanation, so it took me a long time to solve.
It works only with Mozilla Firefox. Please see the code below.(Check Output on Mozilla FireFor)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Table
        </title>
        <style>
td,th{
text-align: center;

}
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
        <table border="1"  cellpadding="5px">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="3">Day</th>
                    <th colspan="3">Seminar</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">Schedule</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">Topic</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Begin</th>
                    <th>End</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
    
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2">Monday</td>
                    <td rowspan="2">8:00 a.m</td>
                    <td rowspan="2">5:00 p.m</td>
                    <td>Introduction to XML</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Validity: DTD and Relax NG</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="4">Tuesday</td>
                    <td>8:00 a.m</td>
                    <td>11:00 a.m</td>
                    <td rowspan="2">XPath</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2">11:00 a.m</td>
                    <td rowspan="2">2:00 p.m</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2">XSL transformation</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2:00 p.m</td>
                    <td>5:00 p.m</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Wednesday</td>
                    <td>8:00 a.m</td>
                    <td>12:00 p.m</td>
                    <td>XLS Formatting Objects</td>
                </tr>
    
            </tbody>
        </table>
    
    
    
<p>By Umer Khalid</p>

</body>

</html>
```

[Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqprO.png)

Comment: It's not looking same as given output.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Time Table">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Time Table</title>
</head>

<body>
   



    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Time Table">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Time Table</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Table->1 -->
        <p>
            <strong>TABLE : 1</strong>
        </p>
        <br>
        <table border="2" cellspacing="0" width="500" height="400" cellpadding="8">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="12">
                        TCB
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Order no:
                    </th>
                    <td colspan="4">
                        #ABC001
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <th>
                    Order Date:
                </th>
                <td colspan="4">
                    23-Mar-2022
                </td>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4">
                        Customer
                    </th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Name:
                    </th>
                    <td colspan="4">
                        John Paps
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <th>
                    Address:
                </th>
                <td colspan="4">
                    Independence Day 5th str, 11511
                </td>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4">
                        Order Details
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        1
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Of Mice and Men
                    </td>
                    <td>book</td>
                    <td align="center">10.00$</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        2
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Les Miserables
                    </td>
                    <td>book</td>
                    <td align="center">12.00$</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        3
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Game of Thrones-S01
                    </td>
                    <td>DVD</td>
                    <td align="center">50$</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        4
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Samsung Galaxy
                    </td>
                    <td>Mobile Phone</td>
                    <td align="center">200$</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="3" align="right">
                        Total:
                    </th>
                    <td align="center">
                        272.00$
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        <br>

        <!-- Table->2 -->
        <p>
            <strong>TABLE : 2</strong>
        </p>
        <br>

        <table border="2" cellspacing="0" width="400" height="200" cellpadding="8">
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">

                </td>
                <th colspan="2" align="center">Average</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Red eyes</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th align="center">Height</th>
                <th align="center">Weight</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Males
                </th>
                <td>
                    1.9
                </td>
                <td>
                    0.003
                </td>
                <td>40%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Females
                </th>
                <td>
                    1.7
                </td>
                <td>
                    0.002
                </td>
                <td>43%</td>
            </tr>


        </table>


        <!-- Table->3 -->
        <p>
            <strong>TABLE : 3</strong>
        </p>
        <br>

        <table border="2" width="600" height="300" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="8">
            <tbody>

                <!-- Part->1 -->


                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="3">Day</th>
                    <th colspan="3">Seminar</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">Schedule</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">Topic</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Begin</th>
                    <th>End</th>
                </tr>

                <!-- Part->2 -->

                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2">Monday</td>
                    <td rowspan="2">8:00 am</td>
                    <td rowspan="2">5:00 pm</td>
                    <td align="center">Introduction to XML</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td align="center">Validity: DTD and Relax NG</td>
                </tr>

                <!-- Part->3 -->

                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="3">Tuesday</td>
                    <td>8:00 am</td>
                    <td>11:00 am</td>
                    <td rowspan="2" align="center">XPath</td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>11:00 am</td>
                    <td>2:00 pm</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2:00 pm</td>
                    <td>5:00 pm</td>
                    <!-- <td rowspan="2">XSL transformation</td> -->
                    <td align="center">XSL transformation</td>
                </tr>

                <!-- Part->4 -->

                <tr>
                    <td>Wednesday</td>
                    <td>8:00 am</td>
                    <td>12:00 pm</td>
                    <td align="center">XLS Formatting Objects</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>

    </html>




    <!-- Table->3 -->
    <p>
        <strong>TABLE : 3</strong>
    </p>
    <br>

    <table border="2" width="600" height="300" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="8">
        <tbody>

            <!-- Part->1 -->


            <tr>
                <th rowspan="3">Day</th>
                <th colspan="3">Seminar</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Schedule</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Topic</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Begin</th>
                <th>End</th>
            </tr>

            <!-- Part->2 -->

            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">Monday</td>
                <td rowspan="2">8:00 am</td>
                <td rowspan="2">5:00 pm</td>
                <td align="center">Introduction to XML</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="center">Validity: DTD and Relax NG</td>
            </tr>

            <!-- Part->3 -->

            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3">Tuesday</td>
                <td>8:00 am</td>
                <td>11:00 am</td>
                <td rowspan="2" align="center">XPath</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>11:00 am</td>
                <td>2:00 pm</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2:00 pm</td>
                <td>5:00 pm</td>
                <!-- <td rowspan="2">XSL transformation</td> -->
                <td align="center">XSL transformation</td>
            </tr>

            <!-- Part->4 -->

            <tr>
                <td>Wednesday</td>
                <td>8:00 am</td>
                <td>12:00 pm</td>
                <td align="center">XLS Formatting Objects</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<table style="width: 50%;"> 
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="3">Day</th>
    <th colspan="3" style="text-align: center;">Seminar</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">schedule</th>
    <th rowspan="2" colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Topic</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Began</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">End</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Monday</th>
    <td rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;">08:00 a.m.</td>
    <td rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;">11:00 p.m.</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">Introduction to xml</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;">Validity: DTD and Relax NG</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="3" style="text-align: center;">tuseday</th>
    <td style="text-align: center;">8:00 a.m.</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">11:00 p.m.</td>
    <td rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Xpath</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11:00 a.m.</td>
    <td>2:00 p.m.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2:00 a.m.</td>
    <td>5:00 p.m.</td>
    <td rowspan="1" style="text-align: center;">XSL transformations</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Wensday</th>
    <td>8:00 a.m.</td>
    <td>12:00 p.m.</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">XLs formating objects</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when I was doing this assignment today and I had seen some answers here, they're correct but were not working for me. The thing I found out is that It is true there are 4 rows in Tuesday among which 2 are given for XPath and 2 for XSL Transformations along with this 1 row is given for 8:00am time 2 for 11:00am and 1 for 2:00pm.
But it was not working for me and XPath was ending just in the same row of 11:00am. So, along with given approach here you may set,
height attribute in td tag of XPath. That will solve the problem if it's happening even after using the approach answered here.  Check XPath line in given code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Time Table</title>

    <style>
        table,
        tr,
        th,
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        tr,
        th,
        td {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <caption>Time Table for seminar</caption>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="3" width="70">Day</th>
                <th colspan="3" width="500">Seminar</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Schedule</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Topic</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Begin</th>
                <th>End</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">Monday</td>
                <td rowspan="2">8:00 a.m.</td>
                <td rowspan="2">5:00 p.m.</td>
                <td>Introduction to XML</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Validity: DTD and Relax NG</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="4">Tuesday</td>
                <td>8:00 a.m.</td>
                <td>11:00 a.m.</td>
                <td rowspan="2" height="28">XPath</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">11:00 a.m.</td>
                <td rowspan="2">2:00 p.m.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">XSL Transformations</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2:00 p.m</td>
                <td>5:00 p.m.</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Wednesday</td>
                <td>8:00 a.m.</td>
                <td>12:00 p.m.</td>
                <td>XSL Formatting Objects</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
        <tfoot>

        </tfoot>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the correct code(tested). You need to add some height to 'XPath' to increase the length of the cell. Also, you need to remember, there are 4 rows instead of three.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="10px">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="3">Day</th>
                <th colspan="3">Seminar</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Schedule</th>
                <th rowspan="2" colspan="2">Topic</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Begin</th>
                <th>End</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">Monday</td>
                <td rowspan="2">8 am</td>
                <td rowspan="2">5 pm</td>
                <td>Introduction to XML</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Validity: DTD and Relax NG</td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="4">Tuesday</td>
                <td>8 am</td>
                <td>11 am</td>
                <td rowspan="2" height="42">XPath</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">11 am</td>
                <td rowspan="2">2 pm</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">XSL Transformation</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>2 pm</td>
                <td>5 pm</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Wednesday</td>
                <td>8 am</td>
                <td>12 pm</td>
                <td>XSL Formatting Objects</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```