# HTML Table with complex structure

Tags: html, html-table

I am having difficulty in creating the table in the image below:

[complex table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keFLs.png) (the image itself is not appearing, please click on the link)

I have searched on stackoverflow but the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22311309/html-table-complex-layout-specificel) is given without much explanation. Below is the code only for the complex row, that is the row that starts with cell containing "Tuesday"

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="6">Tuesday</td>
    <td rowspan="2">8:00 am</td>
    <td rowspan="2">11:00 am</td>
    <td rowspan="3">XPath</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">11:00 am</td>
    <td rowspan="2">2:00 pm</td>
    <td rowspan="3">XSL Transformations</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">2:00 am</td>
    <td rowspan="2">5:00 pm</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

With the above code, I am using three TRs, that is expected to produce three rows but only one row is being produced. The result of the above code is shown below. I am failing to understand why the row starting with "11:00 am", that is the circled row is not on a new line.

[actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXuae.png)(the image itself is not appearing, please click on the link)

Comment: rowspawn = 2 means 2 cells, so for each row you can sum up the cells.
sum should be equal for each row.

Comment: yes, agree, but try it, you will see that it gives you a weird result

Comment: sorry, rowspawn s for vertical/column cells, for row wise you do colspawn

Comment: the problem is you must know the number of rows and column to do this.because rowspawn and colspawn should be balanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created the structure for 6 rows, but your markup had only 3, and the 2nd row contained both spanned cells from the 1st row and the cells defined in the 2nd row. That's why the browser tried to stack them horizontally.

To get the desired result, you should add 3 extra rows to your table and distribute cells between them so that each cell starts in the correct row ("XSL Transformations" in the 4th row, others in the 1st, 3rd and 5th rows respectively): see 1st example below.

By the way, the same visual result can be achieved with only 4 rows: see the 2nd example below.

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="6">Tuesday</td>
    <td rowspan="2">8:00 am</td>
    <td rowspan="2">11:00 am</td>
    <td rowspan="3">XPath</td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr><!-- needed to accomodate cells with rowspan="2" from above -->
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">11:00 am</td>
    <td rowspan="2">2:00 pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">XSL Transformations</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">2:00 am</td>
    <td rowspan="2">5:00 pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr><!-- needed to accomodate cells with rowspan="2" from above -->
</table>

<hr>

<table border="1">
  <tr><!-- row 1 -->
    <td rowspan="4">Tuesday</td><!-- spans rows 1-4 -->
    <td>8:00 am</td><!-- spans row 1 only -->
    <td>11:00 am</td><!-- spans row 1 only -->
    <td rowspan="2">XPath</td><!-- spans rows 1-2 -->
  </tr>
  <tr><!-- row 2 -->
    <td rowspan="2">11:00 am</td><!-- spans rows 2-3 -->
    <td rowspan="2">2:00 pm</td><!-- spans rows 2-3 -->
  </tr>
  <tr><!-- row 3 -->
    <td rowspan="2">XSL Transformations</td><!-- spans rows 3-4 -->
  </tr>
  <tr><!-- row 4 -->
    <td>2:00 am</td><!-- spans row 4 only -->
    <td>5:00 pm</td><!-- spans row 4 only -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have a question, why an entire row for ""XSL Transformations"", can't it be a in a TD affter the TD containing 2:00 pm ?

Comment: It can't be in the same row with them because those two cells span one cell from the row _above it_ and one cell from the row where this cell starts. So these cells have to start in different rows, not in the same.

Comment: I added some comments to my 2nd example to clarify which cell belongs to which rows. Maybe it helps to understand why they should be placed the way they are.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="3">Day</th>
            <th colspan="3">Seminar</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Schedule</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Topic</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Begin</th>
            <th>End</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Monday</td>
            <td rowspan="2">8:00 a.m.</td>
            <td rowspan="2">5:00 p.m.</td>
            <td>Introduction to XML</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Validity: DTD and Relax NG</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4">Tuesday</td>
            <td>8:00 a.m.</td>
            <td>11:00 a.m.</td>
            <td rowspan="2" style="padding: 7px;">Xpath</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">11:00 a.m.</td>
            <td rowspan="2">2:00 p.m.</td>
        </tr>
        <td rowspan="2">XSL Transformations</td>
        <tr>
            <td>2:00 p.m.</td>
            <td>5:00 p.m.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Wednesday</td>
            <td>8:00 a.m.</td>
            <td>12:00 p.m.</td>
            <td>XSL Formatting Objects</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>enter code here
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You maybe just should remove rowspan from hour's  to obtain a better result.

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="6">Tuesday</td>
    <td>8:00 am</td>
    <td>11:00 am</td>
    <td rowspan="3">XPath</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11:00 am</td>
    <td>2:00 pm</td>
    <td rowspan="3">XSL Transformations</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2:00 am</td>
    <td>5:00 pm</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm not sure to understand want you want, can you post a drawing of the expected result?